# Unable to use StringBuilder to concatenate chars to String

Tags: java, string, char, concatenation

BThis is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String teacherName = "Benjamin Brown";
    int teacherSecondInitialIndex = (teacherName.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    String teacherInitials = new StringBuilder(teacherName.charAt(0)).append(teacherName.charAt(teacherSecondInitialIndex)).toString();
    System.out.println(teacherInitials);
}
```

I want to print out the initials of teacherName, which would be "BB". But only "B" is being printed out. What is the issue?

Comment: Why is it "BG" and not "BB" ?

Comment: My bad, you're right. Edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder%28int%29)

```
new StringBuilder(teacherName.charAt(0))
```

accepts an `int`. So the `char` value you are passing is being widened and used as the `StringBuilder` capacity, not as the first `char` in the underlying `String`.

Create an empty `StringBuilder` and append two chars.

```
String teacherInitials = new StringBuilder()
        .append(teacherName.charAt(0))
        .append(teacherName.charAt(teacherSecondInitialIndex))
        .toString();
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that.